# PHP Curl SFTP download working local but not on the server

Tags: php, curl, sftp

I've picked bits of code here and there to make sure I can download a file directly in the browser from an sFtp server.

When I run the script locally it works perfectly, it downloads the file just fine. When I upload it on my ubuntu 20.04 server and go to the url in the browser. Get notified that he wants to download. Only the file is only 0 bytes.

**The script:**

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"demo.pdf\""); 

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "sftp://".$host."/demo.pdf");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Curl PHP extension is installed on the server.

(Edit) Fix (i think):

When i add the following lines. It will work:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: You will need to check the output from `curl_error()`

Comment: @Nico Haase: Add curl_error() check. But it will not give any output. Test directly curl on the server maybe there was a firewall issues i don't know. But that is working.

Comment: So try other things to debug the problem. For example, set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` and call `curl_getinfo()`.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl thanks for the reply. I cust check curl_getinfo('request_header') and other parameters but i only get a 0 at the http_code.

Comment: Do `curl_getinfo($curl)` and dump the returned array. + What does `curl_exec` return when you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`?

Comment: @Martin Prikryl When i put curl_getinfo in a array, most of the vaules give 0. (https://pastebin.com/raw/Gc39R8jJ).

Answer (score -1):

Please check your php.ini settings and confirm that curl_exec function isn't disabled there. You can also check the web server log to find out more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have check my php.ini file and its enabled. And the webserver error log is empty. But i think found the solution and edit my post :)

Answer (score -1):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Comment: Setting these is a security flaw. Instead of the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`, set `CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5`. The `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` has no effect on SFTP connections. Also if host key is a problem, the `curl_error()` should return *"SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK"*.